# Weird Grails type resolution between jar and grails after creating and deleting service

Tags: grails

I have a grails app that uses functionality from a set of custom java libs. All the libs are compiled into JARs and then injected as dependencies into my grails up where they are in turn used by Grail's controllers and services.

It just so happened that I created a grails service with the same class name as one in my libs,e.g. MyGrailsApp.MyService and then there's another service called MyLib.MyService. Even though I've deleted the service in grails, all of the MyService types in my controllers resolve to MyGrailsApp.MyService but it doesn't exist! Where is this thing? I have to fully qualify all my service types with this name, and that's sad, very sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you actually deleted the class and run a Grails `clean` this should help.